# How to run memory_profiler in python inside 3D Studio Max

Tags: python, memory-leaks, 3dsmax

I am writing a script for 3ds Max. I think tak it has some sort of memory leackage, it is getting slow after some time. That's about 3000 lines of code and there are many different variables, I cannot determinate what causes this problem.

So I thought that I can use [memory_profiler](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler)
The problem is, that I cannot run it form inside of 3ds max. Python is installed with this software and can be only run with command(in MaxScript, internal 3ds max language):

```
python.Execute "print 'hello'"
```

or

```
python.ExecuteFile "demoBentCylinder.py"
```

So I think so the only way to run the memory profiler would be to run a command:

```
python -m memory_profiler script.py
```

From a running script, in a simmilar way to execfile() (I know that execfile only imoports code)

Is this possible? Is there other waty to run memory_profiler on my code?

Regards